# Which is best way GridView / Table with data binding in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview, data-binding

I made simple notice table with asp ListView looks like this.

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

ㅣ  Number ㅣ Name ㅣ

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

ㅣ**** Contents ******ㅣ

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

But it shows just one table, so I'm trying to change ListView to GridView or asp:Table. What is useful way with data binding? Or please suggest the best way :) And could you give me the example ?

*Note: I saw asp:Table can't do data binding... Is it true?

Comment: What do u mean by best way... are you talking about the design principles or you want to know the ways of binding grid like bind to List or Datatable etc.

Comment: No. I mean which thing people mostly use like this example. I tried asp:table, but didn't find the way to data bind.. :/ I found other way, gridView then people said don't use much hh. So I want to know what way to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer Asp.net GridView as it has data bind properties which makes it very easy to use. GridView ultimately generates HTML tables when rendered on the browser.

Comment: Thanks :) Because of your suggestion, I found GridView example what I want .